# How can I redirect the output to be put into a file in python (version 3.3.3)?

Tags: python

```
sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY"
s = sentence.split() 
another = [0]
print(sentence)
for count, i in enumerate(s): 
    if s.count(i) < 2:
        another.append(max(another) + 1)
    else:
        another.append(s.index(i) +1)
another.remove(0)
print(another)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want the sentence put into a text file? If so, here is the code:

```
text_file = ("textfile.txt", "w")
text_file.write(sentence)
text_file.close()
```

Make sure textfile.txt is in the same folder as your program.